# Joomla jgrid.published not working

Tags: joomla2.5, backend

I got a code like this in joomla backend.

```
<td class="center"><?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $item->published, $i, 'products.', TRUE, 'cb'); ?></td>
```

The publish function work correctly sending me to my controller products and method publish. However, the unpublish was not correct it send me to publish method instead of unpublish method, even though the anchor tag still show correctly like this `<a class="jgrid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return listItemTask('cb7','products.unpublish')" title="Unpublish Item">`

anyone got any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really really old question, but I just came across the same problem myself.

It looks like they are saving space by using the same method (which you pointed out) "publish" for both publish and unpublish functionality.

The problem is that in the method it checks how to set the state, but does so based on the "task" which for some reason does not strip the context of the controller out of the post data. So... instead of looking for...

```
if( $post['task'] == 'unpublish' ){
```

...you should be looking for...

```
public function publish(){

    $post = JRequest::get('post');

    if( $post['task'] == 'items.unpublish'){
       $state = 0;
    }else{
      $state = 1;
    }
```

Notice how the `task` we are looking for is `items.unpublish` (items being your controller) instead of just `unpublish`.

I know this is probably way to late, but hopefully it helps someone.